# Checking if window has keyboard focus again

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, jframe, awt

**Preface**

I'm designing an application which will at one stage have it's keyboard focus taken away and redirected to another application.  The application in question is Google-Chrome.  At this stage my program should pause, or halt it's operations entirely until keyboard focus has been returned.

Some extra information:

- My application is being written in Java
- The application that is granted Keyboard focus is Google-Chrome

***What I need***

A way to test if a `JFrame` has keyboard focus maybe like:

```
JFrame.hasScreenFocus()
```

or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `WindowListener` and listen for the `windowActivated()` event. You would also probably need to listen for `windowDeactivated()` to stop your current processing.

Answer (score 2):

Make any other pop-up a modal dialog and it becomes a very simple question.  The focus will return to the parent window the code line after the line which calls `dialog.setVisible(true)`.

See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't think I was clear enough in my post though, I'm not passing keyboard focus to another Window created within my own program.  It is a window on a separate program that will grab keyboard focus and I need to wait until it has been returned to continue the program.  If this helps clarify my question I'll update the OP.